# <a> click not working but href is right and works

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I want to make a redirection of a pdf base64 with an `a` tag, but when it is clicked it does nothing, also if I check it with the devtools of the browser and click on the href link it actually redirects me to the pdf
code:

```
<a [href]="fileSrc">a</a>
```

ts to get the source of the file
getImgData() {

```
let chooseFile = document.getElementById(this.idF) as HTMLInputElement;
let imgPreview = document.getElementById(this.fileId) as HTMLEmbedElement;
let files = chooseFile.files[0];
if (files) {
  this.globalFile = files;
  let fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(files);
  fileReader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    imgPreview.src = this.result as any ;
  })
  return true
}else{
  const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
  if(this.globalFile != null)
  if(chooseFile.files.length == 0)
  dataTransfer.items.add(this.globalFile);
  chooseFile.files = dataTransfer.files;
  // chooseFile.files = this.globalFile;
  return false
 }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're working in Angular. You should include that in the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need some type of click event to make it fire.

```
<a [href]="fileSrc" (click)="openPdf(fileSrc)">a</a>

openPdf(fs) {
  window.open(fs, '_blank');
}
```

Comment: It seems that already it has it, I received this error 
Hmmm… can't reach this pageIt looks like the webpage at data:application/pdf;base64,data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjcNCiW1tbW1DQoxID

Comment: If you copy the `href` and open it yourself, does it work?

Comment: yes, when I copy the href or click it it works, but with yours doesnt work

Comment: it gives me the same error

Comment: Got it. Sounds like you just need some type of click event to make it fire. I updated the code above to something that should work.

Comment: I got this error Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL:

Comment: The error message "Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL" suggests that the browser is blocking the window.open() method because it is trying to navigate the top frame to a data URL. With f12 on your console tab - you should be able to see which level you're at. Does it say `top`?

Comment: yes it says that I'm at top and then my ip

Comment: After that I found this,
  var win = window.open();
    win.document.write('<iframe src="' + base64URL  + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>');

Comment: and with what you helped me it worked, thank you a lot